# What is the format used by pyspark when getting a DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In `pyspark`, when I read data from Apache Spark into a `DataFrame`, what is the format used under the hood to transfer the actual data frame? In other words, how is the data frame serialized by Apache Spark before being transfered to the client?

Comment: [Parquet](https://databricks.com/session/in-memory-storage-evolution-in-apache-spark).